# Can database work be done with PHP instead of MongoDB in METEOR?

Tags: javascript, php, meteor, web

I'm developing an application using meteor.js, though meteor has MongoDB for database work by default, but I have excellent working hand on PHP, so can PHP be used with meteor.js?

Comment: In what way? What is it you're trying to do? You need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: You can use the ddp protocol to communicate between your meteor app and your php app. https://github.com/zyzo/meteor-ddp-php